# How to read female clothing labels in Poland?

Tags: shopping, poland, clothing

I am in Poland and my girlfriend asked me to buy some tights for her. There is this very strange chart on the package I just don't understand.

Y-axis has label `height` and x-axis has label `weight`. That makes sense.  However, there is also `hips` label right above the chart, as if x-axis was also labelled `hips`. How should I read this chart? How could a 2D chart describe a relationship between 3 variables?

Let's assume I get some result based on my girlfriend's measures. What does the result mean? What is this `2-3-4` and why are these areas green, red and yellow?

[image]

Comment: Seems size 2 tights are for women 157-167 cm tall, weighing 55-76 kg having a hips size (circumference maybe?) of 85-110 cm. i may be wrong thought that's what i get from the graph

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about sizing charts for clothing and not travel.

Comment: I voted to re-open as it is something most men only will encounter while traveling.

Comment: That label is exactly the same as in any other country.  This is totally unrelated to travel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no connection at all to travel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Women come in different shapes, some carry their weight well spread all over or do not carry extra weight, others carry more on the belly and waist area, those are the basic left of the chart.
Some girls though keep most of the extra weight on the hips and upper legs. If you have a standard tights but she is wide there, they would not stretch enough, therefore they do have extra line at the top.

Now think about your girlfriend, look for the row with how tall she is in centimeters.
Find her weight at the bottom, but allow for the diversion of the weight as indicated by the top row.
The wider the hips and upper legs, the bigger the size she needs.

Basically they sell a small, a medium and a large, (or XS/S, M, L/XL) as indicated by the numbers 2 to 4, but they are kind enough to indicate which metric sizes fit in which size categories.

The colours seem randomly chosen, just to help you see the different categories more easily.

As pointed out in a comment, err on the bigger side if unsure.
A bigger size of tights will always fit, if not as nicely, a smaller pair may not fit and are uncomfortable if you manage to squeze yourself in.
The thicker and warmer the tights the more important to buy bigger rather than smaller. Bigger thick tights are warmer than the right size.

Comment: If the relevant points on top and bottom axis (hips/weight) for her height point to different sizes, buy the larger of the two.

Comment: ...unless she's sensitive about size, in which case play safe and just send her the image of the chart and let her figure it out!

Comment: It mostly depend on whether it is a 'need something, get me one' or 'you go to a country where I know they sell what I want, get me what I need in decent numbers' and in this last case just buy the size she indicates.